# OAuthPrompt is never invoked in BotFramework v4

Tags: c#, botframework

So my bot has simple code that detects LUIS intents and triggers a `SignInDialog` for a specific intent. However, my prompt is never invoked in `emulator`

I've setup `Azure AD v2` application with redirect settings as

[image]

The application has following delegated Graph Permissions

[image]

In Azure Portal, I've created a connection and entered the `clientId/secret` and same `Scopes` (case-sensitive) with the connection name `MyOAuth` so my bot configuration looks like,

```
{
  "type": "generic",
  "id": "364",
  "name": "Authentication",
  "url": "",
  "configuration": {
    "Azure Active Directory v2": "MyOAuth"
}
```

My `SignInDialog` is same as [Enterprise Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.enterprise-bot/Dialogs/SignIn/SignInDialog.cs), so now when I run the code in `emulator`, my bot is going into loop and not showing `OAuthPrompt` at all

[image]

I installed `ngrok` to inspect the requests, after LUIS analysis the subsequent request `GET /api/usertoken/GetToken` takes 0ms with blank response body/header

[image]

I tried this with GitHub too. Can you please suggest if I'm missing any step?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your bot on the azure portal? I will also suggest you to take a look at following blog post from the bot framework blog
https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/testing-authentication-to-your-bot-using-the-bot-framework-emulator/
I am also working on a bot which uses Oauth card and will update the further findings here

Comment: Yes I have registered the Bot on Portal and Tested the connection and it is successful but not in the emulator